# Making Augmented Reality with Dynamic Content

Tags: content-management-system, augmented-reality

Im trying to create an app with a very simple but apparently unexplored concept:

I want to be able, throught a website, to upload targets and the multimedia associated to them, and store them in some kind of backend.

Then I want to be able, in my application (lets say android for default, but multi-platform would be neat), to be able to sync my device to the "target-multimedia" database, updating my local storage when changes were detected.

This would allow me to, at any moment, add a new target and associations, through a friendly management website client, then every phone with the application would recognize the new target and show the associated multimedia bound to it.

Now, I've been researching a lot about the recent technologies that would allow me to achieve such a thing. The main techs of the moment are Vuforia and easyAR and wikitude for what I've found.
The problem is that I need it as FREE.I can develop the whole system on my server if it's necessary but I can't find any open source SDK that provide AR recognition and other stuff.
what is solution? CAN I BUILD an AR APP with MY OWN DYNAMIC CONTENT MANAGEMENT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TLDR;*** Yes it's possible to build an Augmented Reality App with a custom backend CMS, but there are many considerations and decisions to be made (details below).

The concept you are referring to is not unique, nor is it unexplored. [Blippar](https://www.blippar.com/) has been doing this since 2011 and [Zappar](https://www.zappar.com/)/[Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/)/[Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/) all do something similar except they use QR codes for the marker-lookup. As a former solutions engineer at Blippar, I can provide you with some insight as to the high level concepts you need to explore.

Assuming you are ready to build a CMS backend system for storing all the markers, a concern to keep in mind is that your Augmented Reality CMS should not be constantly checking and trying to sync your markers to the device as mentioned above (*its not scalable*). I would suggest you send the image to the server and have the server do the matching. The draw back here is the amount of data that you will be sending over the network, and the lag in recognition due to the server request/matching/response process that will allow for the marker lookup. You could use a QR code to make the lookup faster but then you have to manipulate the marker images (*trade-off*).

The next major hurdle you will face will be the 3D model formats that you want to support. In order for your application to be cross platform you will need to make a decision on a custom implementation of a cross-platform render engine ([openGL](https://www.opengl.org/), [Vulkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)), etc). The reason you would need to  custom render engine is because SceneKit (*iOS*) nor SceneForm (*Android*) don't share feature parity so if you use the native engines you will be limited to their shared functionalities. You could also choose to implement your solution using an existing game engine (*Unity, Unreal, etc.*) but if you go that route you might as well pay the fee and build atop Vuforia.

So let's assume you want to implement a custom render engine, this is also a heavy lift that has quite a few trade-offs and considerations.

Let's start from the top, if you implement openGL or Vulkan or any other render engine from scratch then you have to implement your own scene-graph, shaders, etc. Implementing your own scene-graph and all the details that come with it is a heavy lift. The other option is use an off the shelf library ([OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/about/features), [Vulkan Scene Graph](https://github.com/vsg-dev/VulkanSceneGraph)). If choose an off the shelf solution you are limited by that library's implementations, but generally not a huge deal unless you want to get into customizations.

There is a third option, you could built your AR CMS using the mobile web. Libraries such as [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js) uses [Aframe](https://aframe.io/) for rendering (*built on top of [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)*) and [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) for image tracking (*using ARToolKit to generate the marker files*). You could use QR codes as part of the marker. Even though there is the tradeoff of manipulating the marker image to include the QR code, you gain much more with the lookup because each QR code could load the webpage directly associated with the experience, no need to sync markers or anything.

Comment: I don know how to say thank you ... you were very very helpful :)